# Как хранить параметры для нескольких каналов прибора (как наследовать static переменные)

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

Здравствуйте, подскажите как правильно хранить множество настроек прибора. Есть программка для прибора, где много-много каналов (1,2,3, ...до 20), ну и для каждого канала есть свои параметры (тип сигнала, верхний предел, нижний предел, верхний предел измерений, нижний предел измерений и т.д....). Соответственно, каждый параметр для каждого канала должен быть постоянным, Я создал класс:

**Channel1.h**:

```
class Channel1Options
{

public:

    QString GetUnitsName();

    int GetSignalType1();
    int GetSignalType();
    int GetLowerLimit();
    int GetHigherLimit();
    int GetLowerMeasureLimit();
    int GetHigherMeasureLimit();

    void SetSignalType(int newsignaltype);
    void SetLowerLimit(int newsignaltype);
    void SetHigherLimit(int newhigherlimit);
    void SetLowerMeasureLimit(int newlowermeaslimit);
    void SetHigherMeasureLimit(int newhighermeaslimit);
    void SetUnitsName(QString newunit);

    // приватные переменные настроек канала 1

private:

    static int signaltype;
    static int lowerlimit;
    static int higherlimit;
    static int lowermeasurelimit;
    static int highermeasurelimit;
    static int measureperiodsecond;
    static QString unitsname;


};
```

**Channel1.cpp**:

```
void Channel1Options::SetUnitsName(QString newunitname)
{
    unitsname = newunitname;
}

QString Channel1Options::GetUnitsName()
{
    return unitsname;
}
```

Далее для второго канала я делаю класс, наследующий класс для первого канала:
**Channel1.h**:

```
class Channel2Options : public Channel1Options
{

//  переменные настроек канала 2

private:

    static int signaltype;
    static int lowerlimit;
    static int higherlimit;
    static int lowermeasurelimit;
    static int highermeasurelimit;
    static int measureperiodsecond;
    static QString unitsname;

};
```

я хочу, чтобы при создании объектов для класса первого и второго канала, мы могли работать с их параметрами соответственно

**main.cpp**:

```
  Channel1Options a;
  Channel2Options b;

  a.SetUnitsName("Volts");
  b.SetUnitsName("Ampers");

  qDebug() << a.GetUnitsName();
  qDebug() << b.GetUnitsName();
```

В желаемом варианте на выходе должно быть:

> ```
> "Ampers"
> "Volts"
> ```

А на деле:

> ```
> "Volts"
> "Volts"
> ```

Comment: Никак. И вам не нужно столько классов! Используйте один класс и обычные поля. Неизменяемость поля еще не означает что оно должно быть статическим.

Comment: спасибо, но в идеале я хочу сделать что-то подобное: channel1.setunits("Ampers"); channel2.setunits("Volts");

Comment: Так зачем вам тогда два класса и статические поля?

Comment: я не знаю, я ищу корректный способ хранения множества параметров для 20 каналов. Ну и хочу сделать работу с их считыванием и записью  наглядным

Comment: **Так зачем вам тогда два класса и статические поля?**

Comment: Хорошо, мне нужен один класс, и не нужны статические поля.. тогда как создать переменную (например, нижний предел напряжения 2 вольта), которое сохранит своё значение при создании нового объекта моего класса...

Comment: А вы не создавайте новый объект.

Comment: ok. Где мне лучше создать 20 экземпляров объекта ChannelOptions, чтобы я мог к ним обращаться из UI? например, мне по нажатию на кнопку "Сохранить" нужно вызвать метод SetUnitsName() одного из экземпляров

Comment: Если это у вас вызывает такие сложности - создавайте глобальный массив из 20 элементов.

Comment: А вообще, следовало бы передавать их по умному указателю в конструктор формы.

Comment: Решилось использованием sqlLite

Answer (score 1):

Пункт первый - вам не надо наследовать один канал от другого, это не соответствует реалиям. Второй канал **не является** первым. Если уж очень хочется наследования - сделайте общий базовый класс (возможно, абстрактный).

Пункт второй. Ваши `[S/G]etUnitsName` работают со статической переменной в первом классе и ничего не знают о таковой во втором, так что все работает правильно. Наследуете - наследуйте все :)

А вообще - не вижу смысла делать все так, как у вас - через статические поля. Зачем? Очень нужен единственный канал - делайте синглтон, но по сути глобальные переменные зачем плодить?...

Comment: я и хочу использовать один общий базовый класс

Comment: Тогда это - **не** `Channel1`. В нем должна быть только общая для всех каналов функциональность. И еще - параметры у каналов одни и те же? Или *совершенно* разные? Может, имеет смысл один класс канала и коллекция из 20 элементов? Насколько отличается их функциональность? И еще раз - каналы 1, 2, 3... - **являются** *каналами*, но канал 2 **не является** каналом 1...

Comment: Пока функциональность у каналов одинаковая, параметры пока одни и те же (в будущем будут другие).

Comment: Тогда это должен быть один класс, а ваш прибор - содержать 20 экземпляров этого класса.

Comment: Понятно, попробую. Просто боюсь. чтобы экземпляр где-нибудь не затерялся, и данные в нём не пропали.. Конечно же я буду записывать все параметры в файл.